# node.js function not returning value

Tags: node.js

this function works correctly and prints the value on the console but it's not return the value. I tried it like **return resultArray** but it does not work.

Following is the code:

```
const mysql = require('../database/server')

function inse() {
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM information_security`;
    mysql.connection.query(sql, [true], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.error(error.message);
        }
        else {
            var resultArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)))
            console.log(resultArray);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = { inse }
```

Comment: you don't have a return for that value, you are only logging the result to the console

Comment: 1) You do not return anything, 2) You are mixing synchron and asynchron code execution. Callbacks do not return data. They are handled asynchron!

Comment: You could make it a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead and return the value in a resolve method like: `resolve(resultArray)`

Answer (score 0):

Because of the callback in `query()`, `inse` cannot return the value. Instead, you have to pass a function, here called `cb`, to `inse` that will then do something with your resultArray:

```
function inse(cb) {
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM information_security`;
    mysql.connection.query(sql, [true], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            cb(null, error);
        }
        else {
            var resultArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)))
            console.log(resultArray);
            cb(resultArray);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = { inse }
```

Then call your function like this:

```
function handleData(resultArray, error) {
  if(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return;
  }
  // manipulate the resultArray
}

inse(handleData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the arrow function `(error, results, fields) =>`  the return is called within the arrow function, so it returns there, not from the inse function. Also, calling `console.error()` also doesn't give a return type, so even if it worked you still get `undefined` as your answer.